# Magento CE 2.2 - Cookies/Cache/Session issue when Server Load overloads

Tags: magento2.2, cache, session

Aside from the obvious answer of upgrading the amount of CPUs on our webhost to alleviate the traffic and prevent Server Load overloads, we are trying to find out what we can do about the cache/cookie/session issue that comes when the server *does* overload and essentially resets.

We use Cloudflare and mostly default cookie settings for our website;

```
Cookie Lifetime             36000
Cookie Path                 [blank]
Cookie Domain               [blank]
Use HTTP Only               Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode     No
```

We also have set our `Base URLs` and `Base URLs (Secure)` to https:// and our Session Validation section options are all set to `No`

**What happens when server overloads *(for some but not all customers)*:**

Most commonly, they will have products added to their cart, but any time they try to go to checkout, it just sends them back to the home page. With that, I am assuming it is trying to check their cookies to clarify they are who they say they are, same session, whatever it be, and the customers browser data doesn't match with what the overloaded/reset webhost has, thus it boots them back to the homepage. Generally the fix for this is for them to clear their cookies/cache and do a hard reset, or use a different browser which will allow them to carry on normally.

Any ideas whats going on here? Or what we can do to alleviate this issue?

Comment: Do they still have their basket when they get kicked off the checkout?

Comment: Yes their cart stays in tact so to their point everything seems fine, then try to goto checkout and the bounce to homepage every attempt looping begins

Comment: That isn't what I'd expect but anyway... Have you looked at the log files in <magento root>/var/log? There may be something in there. At least on 2.3.x (i don't have a 2.2.x version to check) the checkout url is passed to js via data-mage-init and then it'll send you to the checkout index controller. Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link provides the url which has has checkout hard coded. It does escape the values in the phtml file. The crontoller always redirects to the cart not the homepage on error checks. You'll need to do any digging you can around those files and the logs.

Comment: Appreciate the help @mark-rees ! I will look into that. We also have a redirect within our htaccess that forces the page to load as example.com/store any time you try to just goto example.com -- using something like;  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(store|downloads)/ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/$1 [R=301,L] -- and when the server overloads, the error you receive is too many redirects. Could this be playing a part in both the server overload AND the error of the redirects (redirect to homepage would make sense in that thats the default page for the htaccess redirect)